# Modally present VC from UITabBarController in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm trying to trigger a modal view from the AppDelegate every time the app is opened.  I can see my breakpoint being hit, but the modal never shows. I'm including an image of my storyboard in case it matters.  It's a fairly simple app right now with a 2 tab tab bar controller.

[image]

This is the code I have in the AppDelegate to trigger it.

```
let newVC = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginView")
let view = window?.rootViewController as! UITabBarController
view.selectedViewController?.show(newVC, sender: nil)
```

Comment: where you run the code in appBecomeActive ???

Comment: Read the doc: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621172-selectedviewcontroller
It seems `newVC` is not in the tab bar's controllers array, and your attempting to modally present it from the `selectedViewController` in `AppDelegate` where there probably isn't a selected view controller yet.

Comment: Try `present` instead of `show`

Comment: @Lukas I think you're right.  If I check the selected index it's definitely not right.  Is there a different way I can do it?  Should I just choose the 0 index controller and present it from there?

Comment: @Lukas That was it.  I changed it to just choose the 0 index controller and it worked.  If you want to put that as an answer I'll mark it accepted.

Comment: @Jhorra Ok, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `newVC` is not in the tab bar's controllers array, and you're attempting to modally present it from the [selectedViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontroller/1621172-selectedviewcontroller) in `AppDelegate` where there probably isn't a selected view controller yet.

One solution is to present `newVC` after `viewDidLoad` of the selected view controller (view controller at `selectedIndex`). If the presentation must take place before any of the tab bar's view controllers are loaded, then you might wanna set it as the window's root view controller and set the root to be the tab bar once `newVC` has finished its business.

Comment: Present `newVC` from inside `viewDidLoad` of the selected vc, lets call it _FirstVC_. To prevent repeatedly presenting `newVC`, hold a flag in _FirstVC_ which you set In `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`. Or use a static variable in _FirstVC_ or  _AppDelegate_ to hold the flag.